# SSE Instruction to load Bytes with Zero Extension?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, sse

Let's say I have a pointer to a bunch of `uint8_t`'s in RDI and I want to load 4 `uint8_t`s into XMM0 and use SIMD instructions to multiply it with XMM1 where I have 4 `float` values stored.

How can I load the initial 4 `uint8_t`s into XMM0, so it's always  "aligned", meaning that each "compartment" has it's lower 8 bit with the `uint8_t` and the upper 24 bits are 0? Is there an instruction for that?

I hope my issue is understandable and I am sorry for my very naive explanation of my issue.

```
movdqu xmm0, [rdi]
```

would result in a QWORD loaded, not what I need.

Comment: First of all, I'm no assembly programmer, but I do use SSE in c programming. I don't think there is a single instruction, but once you've done your movdqu you can pshufb the bytes to where they need to be if you have SSSE3. You'll need at least one zero byte though, so you may need to 'and' it with a mask first.

Comment: Which version of SSE can you use?  With SSE2, you're limited to `movd` followed by a sequence of unpack instructions.  With SSSE3 you could use `pshufb`.  SSE4.1 finally brings the desired `pmovzxbd` instruction you need.

Comment: Also, you'll need to convert the integers to floats with cvtdq2ps before multiplying by your other floats vector.

Comment: If you can replace the multiplication-by-float with a 16-bit fixed-point scaling operation (eg `pmulhuw`), then you only need to expand by 2x which you can do with `punpcklbw` (with zero in the other operand).

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Scaling byte pixel values (y=ax+b) with SSE2 (as floats)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32288984) .  (And for the reverse, [How to convert 32-bit float to 8-bit signed char? (4:1 packing of int32 to int8 \_\_m256i)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51778721) / [SSE intrinsics: Convert 32-bit floats to UNSIGNED 8-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29856006))

Answer (score 4):

On regular SSE, you need to

```
  // load 4 bytes (likely you can actually load 8 or 16 bytes for future savings)
  __m128i data = _mm_loadu_si32(input_stream);

  // interleave every byte with zero to cast to (u)int16_t
  data = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(data, _mm_setzero_si128());
  // interleave every word with zero to cast to (u)int32_t
  data = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(data, _mm_setzero_si128());
  // convert the integers to float
  __m128 fdata = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(data);
```

On SSE4.1, there's a single instruction to expand uint8_t to uint32_t

```
    __m128i data = _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_loadu_si32(input_stream));
```

On SSSE3, one can use `vshufb` as in

```
    __m128i data = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(input_stream);
    __m128i shuf = _mm_set_epi8(-1,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,0);
    data = _mm_shuffle_epi8(data, shuf);
```

If the next few operations contain addition with a constant (after multiplication with a constant), then one might be able to convert the original data with `_mm_shuffle_epi8` into a floating point number of the format `float_big + int_small`.

Some examples are `float_big_23 = 1<<23, float_big_15 = 1<<15`, where the formats are `0x4b0000..` or `0x4700..00`. One needs a register to contain both the floats and bytes from the stream -- `floatX .... d0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7`, as in after reading only the top 8 bytes of a register with `__m128 _mm_loadh_pi(input_stream)`. Then with a proper shuffle the 4 floats of `floatX + d0, floatX + d1, floatX + d2, floatX + d3` are generated, requiring the bias to be subtracted. AFAIK, conversion by subtracting the magic value is not faster on any modern x64 than the direct `int`->`float` conversion, but in this operation one can bake in further offsets, saving possibly one `sub/add` instruction, while taking a possible penalty of mixing integer/floating point pipelines.

Comment: `_mm_cvtsi32_si128` takes an `int` by value.  If you have a `char *` in C, use `_mm_loadu_si32(void*)` for a 32-bit load if you have a new enough compiler to support it, or `memcpy` into a `uint32_t` temporary.  (Do *not* `_mm_cvtsi32_si128( *(int*)&char_buf[i] )` or something; that would violate the strict-aliasing rule.)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I ignore the floating point multiplication. I assume using `mulps` isn't really that hard. The real challenge is the conversion, if you can't use fixed-point 16-bit integer instead.

The [intel intrinsics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ig_expand=6095,4338,4340,3859,104,3859,3856,2122,2234,2233,5830,5836,1863,2122&techs=MMX,SSE_ALL&text=_mm_cvtpu8_ps) actually come with an intrinsic that expands into a significant sequence of operations just for that: `_mm_cvtpu8_ps`.  But that's for MMX+SSE1 and isn't a single instruction, and compiles very inefficiently with modern compilers<sup>1</sup>.  In the early days of Intel's intrinsics, they provided more "helper function" intrinsics beyond the `_mm_set` ones, with the same naming scheme as the wrappers for single instructions.

For SSE2 there is no straightforward operation. A manual unpack sequence is good:

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>

void u8ps_sse2(float* out, unsigned char* in)
{
    __m128i in_low = _mm_loadu_si32(in);   // unaligned / aliasing-safe movd load
    __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i as_u16 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(in_low, zero);
    __m128i as_u32 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(as_u16, zero);
    __m128 as_float = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(as_u32);
    _mm_storeu_ps(out, as_float);
   // or just return as_float if you want to do more with it.
}
```

```
u8ps_sse2(float*, unsigned char*):
        movd    xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        pxor    xmm1, xmm1
        punpcklbw       xmm0, xmm1
        punpcklwd       xmm0, xmm1
        cvtdq2ps        xmm0, xmm0
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
        ret
```

SSSE3 can use a `pshufb` to implement the zero-extension.

```cpp
void u8ps_ssse3(float* out, unsigned char* in)
{
    __m128i in_low = _mm_loadu_si32(in);
    __m128i shuffle = _mm_set_epi8(
        -1, -1, -1, 3,
        -1, -1, -1, 2,
        -1, -1, -1, 1,
        -1, -1, -1, 0
    );
    __m128i zero_extended = _mm_shuffle_epi8(in_low, shuffle);
    __m128 as_float = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(zero_extended);
    _mm_storeu_ps(out, as_float);
}
```

```
u8ps_ssse3(float*, unsigned char*):
        movd    xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        pshufb  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        cvtdq2ps        xmm0, xmm0
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
        ret
.LC0:
        .byte   0
        .byte   -1
        .byte   -1
        .byte   -1
        .byte   1
        .byte   -1
        .byte   -1
        .byte   -1
        .byte   2
        .byte   -1
        .byte   -1
        .byte   -1
        .byte   3
        .byte   -1
        .byte   -1
        .byte   -1
```

And finally, SSE4.1 gave us the proper instruction with `pmovzxbd`.

```cpp
void u8ps_sse41(float* out, unsigned char* in)
{
    __m128i in_low = _mm_loadu_si32(in);
    __m128i zero_extended = _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(in_low);
    __m128 as_float = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(zero_extended);
    _mm_storeu_ps(out, as_float);
}
```

```
u8ps_sse41(float*, unsigned char*):
        pmovzxbd        xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        cvtdq2ps        xmm0, xmm0
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
        ret
```

---

###### Footnote 1: using MMX+SSE1 `_mm_cvtpu8_ps`

```cpp
// Highly not recommended.
void u8ps_sse1(float* out, unsigned char* in)
{
                       // strict aliasing violation and not alignment safe
    __m64 in_low = _mm_cvtsi32_si64(*(const int*) in);
    __m128 as_float = _mm_cvtpu8_ps(in_low);
    _mm_storeu_ps(out, as_float);
}
```

Comment: So GCC goes nuts with `_mm_cvtpu8_ps`, Clang emits actual MMX code (writing to MMX registers), and MSVC just rejects it

Comment: @harold Yeah, I was just about to edit the answer. It's weird since the the intrinsics guide marks it as SSE, not MMX

Comment: The `pu` intrinsics are for MMX and do weird things.  I think for clang at least there's a flag to have it implement MMX intrinsics using SSE instructions, but I forgot its name.  Usually there's a corresponding `epu` intrinsic meant for SSE.

Comment: @fuz older GCC generate the same code as Clang so I assume it is this automatic conversion to XMM registers that causes the weird code. Anyway, I've removed that assembly

Comment: `_mm_cvtpu8_ps` includes conversion to `float` (`ps`) so it requires SSE support for `cvtdq2ps`.  But the source operand is `__m64`, an MMX vector, so it'd expect the sequence to include `movq2dq xmm, mm`.  Surprised it was that bad, though, while still not actually touching any MMX regs.

Comment: @PeterCordes while I have you here: GCC puts an extra `pxor xmm1, xmm1` into the SSE2 unpack sequence: https://godbolt.org/z/P589vEfjr That's nonsense, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Homer512 Interesting.  Possibly gcc supports the same feature but whether it's on by default changed.

Comment: `_mm_cvtsi32_si128(*(const int*) in)` is a strict-aliasing violation (unless `in` is aligned by 4, and the `char*` points to anonymous memory that's never accessed with any other type except `int` and `char*`.)  Use `memcpy` into an `int` temporary, or `_mm_loadu_si32` in GCC 11.3 and later, or clang/MSVC from a bit before that.  (It was new in GCC11 but broken before 11.3, shuffling the element to the wrong place.  The fixed version also made it aliasing / alignment safe like it's supposed to be.  [\_mm\_loadu\_si32 not recognized by GCC on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837992))

Comment: @Homer512: Yup, total nonsense. Like it thought it needed separate vectors of 16x u8 = 0 and 8x u16 = 0?  There's no "canned sequence" for any of these intrinsics that it could be expanding later, after an optimization pass that should have noticed it already had a zeroed vector.  It happens with GCC from 4.4 to trunk, but *not* GCC 4.1: https://godbolt.org/z/73GMr43o3

Comment: @PeterCordes They even [hoist it out of the loop](https://godbolt.org/z/dsr4Wz7jG)! Weird. Welp, time to file a bug report

Comment: GCC avoiding MMX / `emms` does mostly explain that insane code-gen for `_mm_cvtpu8_ps` when we look at the definition in headers (and remember this was MMX+SSE1, so the only integer shuffles available were in MMX regs, so four floats needed to combine conversion results from two `cvtpi2ps xmm, mm`.  `_mm_cvtpu8_ps` is defined as one unpack with zero to feed `_mm_cvtpu16_ps` (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6c703b4eb68cbc32de1d62e5b573cb1b9857af29/gcc/config/i386/xmmintrin.h#L675) which does unpack lo/hi , 2x convert, movlhps.  Emulating `cvtpi2ps` wastes several instructions :/.